# Discord.py bot that creates a role with permissions? How to do

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot and I want it to be able to create a role with permissions. I've got

await bot.create_role(server=ctx.message.server, name='Muted')

I'm really not sure how to add permissions= on... Please help me by giving an example and explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were told in the d.py support server that the argument `permissions` in `create_role` wants an instance of [discord.Permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.create_role). This means you create your own Permissions object and pass it to create_role via `permissions=`.
You can create common-use permission objects by using the classmethods `all_channel()` or specify custom permissions you want to allow or deny when you create your permissions object by using the arguments specified in the docs.
Using the commands extension:

```
server = ctx.message.server
perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, read_messages=True)
await client.create_role(server, name='NoSend', permissions=perms)
```